# how to plot nonzero elements of a matrix using levelplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice, levelplot

I have a data frame like this:

```
>x
      r      z   rho
1  2.90 -11.20 0.000
2  2.90 -11.15 0.000
3  2.90 -11.10 0.000
4  2.90 -11.05 0.000
5  2.95 -11.45 0.000
6  2.95 -11.40 0.000
7  2.95 -11.35 0.000
8  2.95 -11.30 0.000
9  2.95 -11.25 0.000
10 2.95 -11.20 0.002
11 2.95 -11.15 0.004
12 2.95 -11.10 0.002
13 2.95 -11.05 0.006
14 3.00 -11.45 0.010
15 3.00 -11.40 0.000
16 3.00 -11.35 0.001

>y
  r      z        rho
1  2.90 -11.20 0.01666389
2  2.90 -11.15 0.01666389
3  2.90 -11.10 0.01666389
4  2.90 -11.05 0.01666389
5  2.95 -11.45 0.03332778
6  2.95 -11.40 0.00000000
7  2.95 -11.35 0.00000000
8  2.95 -11.30 0.00000000
9  2.95 -11.25 0.00000000
10 2.95 -11.20 0.00000000
11 2.95 -11.15 0.00000000
12 2.95 -11.10 0.00000000
13 2.95 -11.05 0.00000000
14 3.00 -11.45 0.00000000
15 3.00 -11.40 0.00000000
16 3.00 -11.35 0.00000000
```

The number of rows is 241401. So it is basically a matrix. r and z can be thought as x and y and rho tells you the value of that specific row,col. I want to plot it using levelplot. Right now I am using something like this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(latticeExtra)
library(lattice)
x <- read.table("fakedata.txt",header=FALSE) 
y <- read.table("fake2.txt",header=FALSE)
colnames(x) <- c("r","z","rho")
colnames(y) <- c("r","z","rho") 
levelplot(y$rho ~ y$r + y$z) 
levelplot(x$rho ~ x$r + x$z)
```

the plots for x and y are: 
[image]
[image]
however, i want to have pink color for all the squares that plot x has as colored and blue color for all the squares that plot y has as colored on the same plot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have ideas and experience with levelplot, but you have provided no test data. I would advise against using `na2d$` in hte formula, since lattice functions generally work better with dataframes being given to the `data` argument.

Comment: @42- would this data be useful for you?

Comment: Looks useful. Will address when I wake up in the morning.

Comment: Now that we have the data, I think it's unclear what you want to have happen for a "square" that is colored on both plots? (which seems to be most of them.)

Comment: @42- if i could use transparent colors, even if two colors are on top of each other, that'd be obvious. Or i could even just assign a color to a specific rho range.

Comment: @42- I've checked my real data, it won't be a problem.